Integration using ImplicitRegion[] or the tranditional form?
I performed the integration using ImplicitRegion[] with the bounds {w1, 0, 1} and {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1}, as well as the straightforward form {w1, 0, 1}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1}. However, the two approaches yield different results. Could you help clarify why this happens and which result is correct?
The code is provided below:
x = 1.497;
integrand = (
  2 ((1 + w1^(2/(3 - 2 x)) - w2) w2)^-x (-1 - w1^((2 x)/(
     3 - 2 x)) + (1 + w1^(2/(3 - 2 x)) - w2)^x + w2^x))/(-3 + 2 x);
reg = ImplicitRegion[(0 < w1 < 1 && w1^(1/(3/2 - x)) < w2 < 1), {w1, 
    w2}];

NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, w2} \[Element] reg]
NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, 0, 1}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1}]
(*1293.75*)
(*1301.32*)

Thank you in advance!

x = 1497/1000;
integrand = (2 ((1 + w1^(2/(3 - 2 x)) - w2) w2)^-x (-1 - 
       w1^((2 x)/(3 - 2 x)) + (1 + w1^(2/(3 - 2 x)) - w2)^x + 
       w2^x))/(-3 + 2 x);
reg = ImplicitRegion[(0 <= w1 <= 1 && 
     w1^(1/(3/2 - x)) <= w2 <= 1), {w1, w2}];

First have a look at the integration limit
Plot[w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), {w1, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All] 


Plot gives a warning message
There is only a small range near w1==1 which contributes to the integration.
If we check the integration areas
Area[reg] (*0.99665*)
NIntegrate[1, {w1, 0, 9/10, 1}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1}] (*0.997009*)
Integrate[1, {w1, 0, 9/10, 1}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1}] // N(*0.997009*)

we recognize a deviation too. Area[reg] deviates around 0.036% from the exact value.
Workaround, similar to onedimensional Method -> "PrincipalValue":
int[eps_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, 0, 1 - eps}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
Table[{eps, int[eps]}, {eps, 10^-Range[0, 7]}]//N 
(*{{1., 0.}, {0.1, 1182.68}, {0.01, 1297.53}, {0.001, 1299.83}, {0.0001,
1299.87}, {0.00001, 1299.83}, {1.*10^-6, 1299.83}, {1.*10^-7,1299.83}}*)
 

This result matches very well
NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, 0, 1 }, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]   (*1299.83*)  

Integration about reg can only be improved marginally
NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, w2} \[Element] reg ] (*1292.65*)
NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, w2} \[Element] DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10000 ]] (*1295.99*)

Hope it helps!

That’s very helpful! Thank you, Neumann. Could you explain why we should choose Method -> "LocalAdaptive"  instead of Method -> Automatic? The results still differ between the two methods.

Another point of confusion is that near w1 == 1 ,  w1^(1/(3/2 - x)) approaches 1, causing the range of w2 to become very small. Does this mean its contribution to the integral is negligible?

@so_sure First question: Method->Automatic gives warning messages, that's why I tried LocalAdaptive. Second question: If you plot the region DiscretizedRegion[reg,MaxCellMeasure->.001] you can see a rounded corner near w1==1,w2==0 which might cause the numerical problems

However, I’m using Mathematica V14.0, and Method -> Automatic works well. Are there any specific options available for LocalAdaptive, such as the number of discretized points? I’d like to explore these settings to verify the differences between the results obtained with Method -> Automatic and LocalAdaptive.

My version is v12.2!  Did you realy  get different results depending on the settings LocalAdaptive and AUtomatic?

Yes, Automatic gives 1301.32.

Try IntegrationMonitor to get the errors: integral =    Reap[NIntegrate[     integrand, {w1, 0, 0.9, 1 }, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1},      Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Automatic}[[+1]],      IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors =           Through[#1@            "Error"]) &)(*errors enthält Fehler der gewählten \ Teilintervalle*)]]; {integral[[1]], Total@errors }. MMA v12.2 gives much smaller errors for Method->"LocalAdaptive"

Yes, using integral =   Reap[NIntegrate[integrand, {w1, 0, 1}, {w2, w1^(1/(3/2 - x)), 1},     Method -> {Automatic, Automatic}[[+1]],     IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors =          Through[#1@           "Error"]) &)(*errors enthält Fehler der gewählten\ \ Teilintervalle*)]]; {integral[[1]], Total@errors} gives an error 0.0012927. Given this, should I place more trust in the LocalAdaptive method?

In this case probably yes!
